# Does Google indexing count as a pageview

Tags: discussion, views, google

I noticed that right after I posted a question, it went from 1 to 2 page-views.  I also noticed that Google is super fast to index SO questions.

Does Google indexing count as a pageview?

Comment: I believe google index with robots and those usually aren't counted as regular users. So I think the answer is **no**. But I can't know for sure.

Comment: I never did get an answer to my [question about the badges](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121475/what-visitors-count-towards-the-publicity-badges). :(

Comment: @animuson:  At least you got the badge for it...

Comment: Since many people look at the front page, it doesn't surprise me that a question has two page views in a short time.

Comment: Google can spider super fast but not as soon as you post a question, pinging the site that much might kill it with load, bing bot is bad enough on that front

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## No, google does not appear to increase the viewcount

This is based on the assumption that all questions are treated equally.

Here is how I checked this:

1. [Search for a question with minimum views](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion%20views%3A0..1), (does not actually work very well)
2. Open [a question with 2 views so far](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25025464/make-axis2-deliver-non-xml-messages-to-service) it had exactly 2 when I opened it,After refreshing it increased to 3 because of me.
3. Note that it also had an upvote, so clearly someone visited it in the past besides the asker
4. Check whether google can find the text in the question, which it can

Comment: I am unsure how you know, with that method, that Google bot did not create a view increment whe it indexed it. Wouldn't have the Google bot increment happened before you viewed the question?

Comment: One view from the author, one from Dennis, and one from whoever upvoted. That leaves no views from the Googlebot.

Comment: @user2357112 ah yeah true